# Unable to read from SD card. android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not working

Tags: android, permissions, adb, android-sdcard

I apologies in advanced because I know this question has been asked hundreds of times but I still can't seem to get it to work. I'll try to be as specific as I can so I don't rehash old threads.

My Goal:

I'm trying to write an Android app that plays MP3 files via the SDCARD. I want the user to be able to copy the MP3s directly to the SD card via a PC/MAC. Yes, I understand that there are hundreds of apps that already do this already.

My Code:

The following snippet is where I'm scanning the a directory looking for MP3s. This is where all my errors seem to be coming from.

```
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC );
    if ( dir == null ) {
        Log.w(TAG,"Directory null ");
        return all;
    }

    if ( ! dir.exists() ) {
        Log.w(TAG,"Creating Data Directory: " + dir.getAbsolutePath() + " = " + dir.mkdirs() );
    }

    File[] children = dir.listFiles();
    if ( children == null ) {
        Log.w(TAG,"listFiles() return null : " + dir.getAbsolutePath() );
        return all;
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG,"listFiles() returned  : " + children.length );
    }
```

And here is my manifest...

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.aloisi.fuegomp3">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Player"></activity>
</application>
```

Results:
When I run the above code in an emulator, it works fine. I'm able to scan the directories and play music. I've tried this with both kinds of emulated SDCARDS.

When I run the above code on a device, I'm getting some version of permission denied.  Depending on how I set the File dir, I'll get any of the following results:

1. dir.exists() = false but dir.mkdirs() fails
2. dir.listFiles() returns null or new File[0];

What I've tried:

1. Every permutation of android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. This seems to have no effect on the results.
2. Tested it on a Kindle Fire (Lollipop) and Galaxy S5 (Marshmallow)
3. Using every various version of Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() or Context.getExternalFiles();

My questions:

In KitKat, it looks like they re-built SD permissions. Is this even still supported? I'm seeing cases where the directories returns by Environment and Context are actually internal storage not external.

Is it possible that my SD cards are formatted with a different file-system type that supports permissions? Even if my App creates a standard /Android/data/package/files/ directory and I copy the files into that directory, then the app still doesn't file the files.

I'm not sure my app is a "trusted" app. Could that be the my problem? I've seen some references to un-trusted apps getting different permissions. If so, how do I make my app trusted when developing it?

Comment: whats your targetSdk?

Comment: [External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) has not been [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on most devices in several years. No permissions are required for `getExternalFilesDir()` on Android 4.4+. For `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, [make sure you have the permission set up properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html).